# Convert Times in SQL so I can Subtract in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

A timeclock table in SQL is storing TimeIn/TimeOut as 1:00p in a format which when i export into excel will not let me subtract and get the time difference.
I was trying to run a query in SQL and convert the times within SQL so that when i export i can subtract. In Access i was using CVDate.

This is the sql code i tried using:

```
Convert (varchar(6), dbo.tblPayrollFlashPunch.TIME_IN, 108) as TimeIn,

CONVERT (varchar(6), dbo.tblPayrollFlashPunch.TIME_OUT, 108) as TimeOut,
```

Any help will be appreciated, btw I am very new to SQL and we are running SQL 2008.

Below is a snapshot of sample data.[image]

(Original here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS8BS.gif )

Edit:  I was hoping SQL could do the conversion so that i could pull the data through a view directly into excel and have the correct format so that my formulas work.  Also, I've tried changing the formats in excel with no success. In MSAccess you can use CVDATE and works great.

Edit 2: Being the noob that I am i just realized we are running SQL Server 2005 which explains why i cant use many of the suggested functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime fields from SQL Server display incorrectly in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598075/datetime-fields-from-sql-server-display-incorrectly-in-excel)

Comment: I am looking to convert within SQL so that i can export correctly to Excel.  Also, when i change formats in Excel it still does not work.  In MS Access i used CVDate and that worked well but i want to crete a VIew in SQL that i can just extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL are you using?

In T-SQL, I believe this would work if your time column is a string/varchar.

```
CONVERT(TIME, (dbo.tblPayrollFlashPunch.TIME_OUT + 'm'), 108) as TimeOut
```

Comment: I get an error when i try to use TIME : "Type TIME is not a defined system type"  any suggestions?

Comment: We are running SQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

What about using DATEDIFF in TSQL to get the difference straight from there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i tried it but no success.  Seems like T-SQL is having issues converting the current times to anything, so the calculations fail.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply
What is the data type of your TIME_IN and TIME_OUT fields?