# CSV file imported from SQL Server has lost data after formatting datetime

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, csv

I have a large CSV file(1.1G) exported from SQL Server, which I would like to pre-process in python, but I had a few problems doing this. The original CSV file datetime values look like this `00:07.5, 00:08.3, 00:48.7`, so I have to manually convert them to `1/12/2015 12:00:07 am, 1/12/2015 12:00:08 am, 1/12/2015 12:00:49 am` in excel by formatting the entire column to make it in `d/m/yy h:mm:ss` format so it's recognisable. But I noticed that the file size had shrank to `36.6 MB` from `1.1G`. I received the excel notification:[Possible Data Lost: Some features might be lost if you save this notebook in the comma-delimited(.csv) format. To preserve these features, save it in an Excel file format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCYxX.png)

I tried to save the file in csv and xlsx format but both resulting in lost rows in the data frame as I read in the files in python and their checked their `shape`: (26137666, 4)(original csv file) vs (1048575, 4)(xlsx file).

My original excel file datetime data looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598075/datetime-fields-from-sql-server-display-incorrectly-in-excel).

My questions are:

1. How to prevent data loss?
2. Is it possible to convert the datetime column format in python?

Comment: Excel doesn't have enough rows to handle that much data, at least not in one sheet.

Comment: @BigBen I think you're right. Any suggestion what I can do?

Comment: I'd really avoid using Excel here to be honest, it's not meant for this much data.

Comment: you should use Pandas for deal this kind data

Comment: From your linked post the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376588/6305294) says "**Excel has the correct value of the DATETIME** (even if the formatting is applied after the paste), but by default doesn't have a built in format to show the SQL DATETIME.". My question to you: why are your formatting dates in Excel if you intend to process this file in Python? All date components are in the CSV file, else how do you think changing the date format would show more data?

Comment: @Alex I’ve formatted data in excel as I’m not sure if python can do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Excel, not python.

I found this subject researching. There is a way to copy all this data to an Excel Datasheet. (I have this problem before with a 50 million line CSV file) If there is any format, additional code could be included. Try this.

```
Sub ReadCSVFiles()

Dim i, j As Double
Dim UserFileName As String
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile

UserFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
Open UserFileName For Input As #iFile
i = 1
j = 1
Check = False

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    If i >= 1048576 Then
        i = 1
        j = j + 1
    Else
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) = strTextLine
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Close #iFile
End Sub
```

Later on you will get all the data in a really heavy file so just split it.